# Inserting data into a Database using PHP (errors but doesn't insert anything);

Tags: php, mysql

Following tutorials I found online and this one basically was showing me how to insert data into a database. I have Database called JapaneseDefinition and I have the table named Japanesewords. I got HTML Code that sends Japaneseword and English into my Database.

I am able to look up a word with a different query, but I am having no such look with the INSERT Query. Can someone look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong with it.

```
                    try{
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=Jamal-PC;dbname=japanesewords',$username,$password);
if(isset($_POST['EnglishWord'])){
$Japaneseword = $_POST ['JapaneseWord'];
$Englishword = $_POST['EnglishWord'];
$q = "INSERT INTO Japanesedefinition(Japaneseword,Englishword)VALUES(:Japaneseword,:Englishword):";
$query = $conn->prepare($q);
$result = $query->execute(array(
'Japaneseword'=>$Japaneseword,
"Englishword"=>$Englishword
));
}
}catch(PDOException $e){
 echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
echo 'hello';
}
myTest();
?>
```

Comment: Can you post what errors you are getting?

Comment: You have a colon at the end of your query, not a semi-colon. Is this a typo on this post, or is it your problem? You also do not check if `Japaneseword` isset, but that probably isn't your issue.

Comment: That colon at the end needs to be removed as well

Comment: Are $username and $password are being set inside the myTest() function as well or just placeholders for the question here?

Comment: is an error being echoed? is error reporting turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the colon's to your execute array keys.

```
$result = $query->execute(array(
':Japaneseword'=>$Japaneseword,
":Englishword"=>$Englishword
));
```

EDIT: if this is not solving the problem AND you removed the colon from the end of your query string (you have `):";` ), then the next step is to check your post data

```
//put this at the top of the script and make sure all your post 
//variables are set as expected
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: @SmithSmithy It was not me who downvoted you, although your initial comment was worthy of it.

Comment: No worries. I did submit a one liner in error and then went back to paste in the revised code block.

Comment: I'm trying that and still not getting any data into my database.

Comment: @SmithSmithy I hardly if ever downvote anyone. I rather point it out first and hopefully add to an answer in order to provide accurate information for the OP/all. ;-)

Comment: at user1459917, bummer... see my revised answer. have you done this already?

Comment: I tried your code SmithSmithy and it returns Array
(
    [EnglishWord] => hi
    [JapaneseWord] => konnichiwa
)

Comment: @SmithSmithy thanks you got it With the extra colon. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You need to precede the token names in your array with a colon, like this:

```
$result = $query->execute(array(
 ':Japaneseword'=>$Japaneseword,
 ":Englishword"=>$Englishword
));
```